# Eclipse Neon, it doesn't import classes under sources inside the IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, directory, jogl

I am having trouble working with jogl (and gluegen) in Eclipse Neon 2.

I am supposed to add specific source folders. It compiles successfully, but I can't see them in the IDE.

This is my configuration:

[image]

[This](https://github.com/sgothel/jogl/tree/master/src/jogl/classes) is supposed to be the main source folder, but as I said, I don't see any file in it..

This is my `.classpath`:

[image]

As you can see, everything looks right, the main folder is the following:

```
<classpathentry excluding="com/jogamp/audio/windows/waveout/TestSpatialization.java|jogamp/opengl/gl2/fixme/" kind="src" output="build/jogl/classes" path="src/jogl/classes">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH_ATTR_LIBRARY_PATH_ENTRY" value="jogl/build/jogl/obj"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

I tried to refresh both projects, but nothing, I still see no sources under source folders:

[image]

What's wrong, guys?

Comment: Are you sure there a `.java` files located unter `build/...`? I would have expected `.class` files only there.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the organization of your `src` folder.

Comment: What is it that you're expecting to see that's missing? Be specific.

Comment: By organization I mean the subfolders (at least the direct ones), which are collapsed in your screenshot

Comment: @P.Merkle yep sure. I am expecting to see some source file. But I found the error, I'll write it in the answer for anyone who has my same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I was doing:

- right click on project, **Properties**
- **Java Build Path**, **Source** tab
- **Add Folder**

I misread "Add Folder" with "Add Source".

What I had to do at the last step was, instead, clicking on **Link Source**